# Cordova build android crasher after adding custom activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

I extended Cordova app for some background receivers and custom activity.

If i trying to run command cordova (ionic) build android i get always this error message.

```
BUILD FAILED
/path/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:601: Invalid file: /path/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/build.xml
```

It seems to be related to the added android-support-v4.jar library.

If i tried to build app using ADT (Eclipse) it throws following excpetion.

```
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345): java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  CordovaActivity cannot be resolved to a type
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  The method onCreate(Bundle) of type HelloCordova must override or implement a supertype method
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  CordovaActivity cannot be resolved to a type
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  CordovaActivity cannot be resolved to a type
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  Config cannot be resolved
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at com.ionicframework.starter.HelloCordova.<init>(HelloCordova.java:25)
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-15 12:36:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anybody who can help me to solve this issue?